# can't run apt-get update

Tags: apt

I'm trying to run apt-get update but there's an error i don't understand.

this is the output with the error:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Sources
 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

subsequently, the package i'm trying to install is failing these errors:

```
 $sudo apt-get install php-pear

The following NEW packages will be installed:
autoconf automake autotools-dev libltdl-dev libltdl7 libtool php-pear php5-dev shtool

The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-mysql
6 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 141 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,223 kB/9,372 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main autoconf all 2.68-1ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main autotools-dev all 20110511.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main automake all 1:1.11.1-1ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main php5-cli amd64 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main php5-mysql amd64 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main php5-curl amd64 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main php5-gd amd64 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main libapache2-mod-php5 amd64 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main php5-common amd64 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libltdl7 amd64 2.4-2ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libltdl-dev amd64 2.4-2ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libtool amd64 2.4-2ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main php-pear all 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main php5-dev amd64 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/autoconf/autoconf_2.68-1ubuntu1_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/autotools-dev/autotools-dev_20110511.1_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/automake1.11/automake_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-cli_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-curl_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-gd_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/libapache2-mod-php5_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtool/libltdl7_2.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtool/libltdl-dev_2.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtool/libtool_2.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php-pear_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_all.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-dev_5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oneiric has reached it's end of life. Check this for more: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/05/10/ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-end-of-life-reached-on-may-9-2013/

Also check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/91821

Comment: YeeApple is right, you're advised to update to a new release, if you wish to stay on Oneiric, follow the steps in the question he linked to.